# Casbah Mongo as scala Array: is this the most elegant way?

Tags: mongodb, scala, casbah

Folks,

Is this the most elegant way to get a scala List out of casbah?

`trains` is a subkey in a doc whose value is an array

I was slightly surprised that I had to do the `instanceOf` and then the `asScala` to get a first class scala list

Could I have done anything better or more idiomatically scala?

```
val mongoconn = MongoConnection("titan"){"traininfo"}{"trains"}
    val result = mongoconn.find()
    println()


    for{
      x<-result.toList
      y<-(x.get("trains").asInstanceOf[BasicDBList]).asScala

    }
    {
      println(y);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

why not a simple

```
val collection = MongoConnection("titan")("traininfo")("trains")
collection.find().foreach(x => x.as[MongoDBList]("train").foreach(t => println(t)))
```

Comment: as[MongoDBList](train) should be as[MongoDBList]("trains")